# Does the IE url length limit apply to content after the "#"?

Tags: internet-explorer, url, fragment-identifier

I have seen many places that IE limits urls to 2000 or so characters in length. I can't figure out, though, does this apply to the portion after the # as well? That part isn't sent to the server so it seems like it might be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually 2083 characters for a URL (which means *all* of the URL) and 2048 characters for a path. See [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) article for details.